# Add a class active to 'li' if the link init has the same using Jquery

Tags: jquery, find, addclass

Am having a menu like this

```
<li> <a href="/home" class="active">Home</a> </li>
<li> <a href="/service">Services</a></li>
```

I want the li in which the link has active have the class "active". So it will become

```
<li class="active"> <a href="/home" class="active">Home</a> </li>
```

I think code can be something like this, but not quite getting it though

```
var $this;
$("ul > li").each(function(){
    $this = $(this);

    if($this.find("> li a.active").length)
      $this.addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: I just noticed that you're setting `$this` to the `li` element, then attempting to search for an `li` that is its child.  If you simply remove the `> li ` from your `find` call, it should work as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you find the element whose class is "active" and get its parent and add class. This could be as simple as:

```
$("a.active").parent().addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the **children()** selector:

```
if($this.children('a.active').size())
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .children() method allows us to search through the immediate children of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but I guess this is the code you are looking for

```
$("ul > li").each(function(index, element){
    if($(element).find("a.active").length > 0) {
       $(element).addClass("active");
    }
}
```